# Fallo al lanzar query POO

Tags: php, poo, php7

Estoy siguiendo un curso en Youtube sobre PHP y al realizar una conexión a base de datos con POO, me salta el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas_php\POO\devuelve.php:13 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas_php\POO\poo.php(7):
> DevuelveProducto->getProducto() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas_php\POO\devuelve.php on line 13

Tengo poca experiencia en POO pero he intentado solucionarlo y no consigo dar con ello. A mí parecer, entiendo que la variable `$conexion` no está almacenando el objeto de conexión `mysqli`.
Por lo que creo que el error está en la clase que conecta con la base de datos, fichero `conexion.php`.
Adjunto todos los ficheros:

`Config.php`

En este fichero creo las variables para la conexión, nada del otro mundo

```
    <?
/*Definir las variables de la conexión*/
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define ('DB_USER', 'root');
define ('DB_PASS', '');
define ('DB_NAME', 'pruebas');
define ('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
?>
```

`conexion.php`

En este creo la clase conexión utilizando el fichero `config.php`

```
<?php
require ("config.php");

class Conexion{
    
    protected $conexion;
    
    public function Conexion(){
        
        $this->conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        
        if($this->conexion->connect_errno){
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos: " . $this->conexion->connect_error;
            return;
        }
        
        $this->conexion->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);
    }
    
}
?>
```

`devuelve.php`

En este fichero es donde me salta el fallo. Exactamente en la línea que destaco
<?php
require ("conexion.php");

```
class DevuelveProducto extends Conexion{
    
    public function DevuelveProducto(){
        
        parent::__construct();        
    }
    
    public function getProducto(){
        
        >>>>>>>>>>>> $resultado = $this->conexion->query('SELECT * FROM personas'); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        
        $producto = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        
        return $producto;
        
    }
    
}
?>
```

`poo.php`

```
    <?php

require 'devuelve.php';

$cosa = new DevuelveProducto();

$array_productos = $cosa->getProducto();
?>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pruebas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <?php
            foreach ($array_productos as $elemento){
                
                echo $elemento["nombre"] . "<br>" .
                    $elemento["apellidos"] . "<br>" .
                    $elemento["edad"] . "<br>" .
                    $elemento["tfn"] . "<br>" .
                    "=====================================";
                
            }
        ?>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, evitar imagenes, los errores van como texto para que sean legibles para todos

Comment: Para empezar, estás definiendo los constructores de una [forma obsoleta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.deprecated.php) y eso puede generar muchos errores. Actualiza tus clases primero.

Comment: @Alexander, ¿que versión de `PHP` estas usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 8.0

Comment: @BetaM más bien hay un problema de jerarquía en su código y de malas prácticas, algunas ya señaladas por Triby en su comentario... Si se analiza el código, la clase `DevuelveProducto` extiende de `Conexion`, se está invocando al `parent` que sería el constructor de la clase padre, el cual no crea la conexión debido a la pésima codificación. Además es un spaghetti hacer extender `DevuelveProducto` de `Conexion`, es como decir que un `Avion` es hijo de un `Pez`. Alexander, considera aplicar la herencia de una forma natural, **pensando en la realidad**, es una de las grandes ventajas de la POO.

Comment: Cierto es @A.Cedano :), ¿por qué no consideras dejarle una respuesta que lo guíe? ayudaría para mas de una persona que siga trabajando así (*he visto por los menos un par de preguntas que tienen un código trabajado similar*)

Comment: Agradecería una ayudita la verdad, les digo, esto lo encontré en un tutorial de Youtube y ahora estoy buscando cosas más actualizas gracias al comentario de Triby

Comment: @Alexander, intenta hacer lo que Triby te señala en su comentario, simplemente cambia el nombre de los métodos constructores a `__construct`

Comment: Hay una cosa que no entiendo y es el hecho de crear la variable `protected $conexion` en la clase `Conexion`

Comment: Además, he averiguado que actualmente, al extender una clase, la clase hijo automáticamente hereda el método constructor del padre sin tener que especificar nada, es cierto o lo estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: @Alexander, eso lo podes aprender leyendo [este articulo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Puedes tal vez incluso considerar a la conexión como un *trait* y así poder reusarla (*es solo una mera opinión*)

Comment: Buenos días chicos!! Tras una pequeña investigación y con la mente más clara por la mañana he solucionado el problema, publicaré la respuesta y agradecería comentarios en cuanto a rendimiento, efectividad y actualidad del código!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publico mi propia solución:

En el fichero `conexion.php` creé una clase encargada de establecer la conexión con la BBDD. Anteriormente, utilizaba un fichero externo donde guardaba los datos de configuración de la conexión. En este caso he optado por agregar estos datos dentro del método constructor. Además, en cuanto a la variable `$conexion`, he elegido hacerla publica para poder emplearla en el fichero `devuelve.php`, que explicaré a continuación de este.

Adjunto código:

`conexion.php`

```
class Conexion{

    public $conexion;

    public function __construct(){

        $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
        $DB_USER = 'root';
        $DB_PASS = '';
        $DB_NAME = 'pruebas';
        $DB_CHARSET = 'utf8';
        
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

        if($this->conexion->connect_errno){
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos: " . $this->conexion->connect_error;
            return;
        }

        $this->conexion->set_charset($DB_CHARSET);

        return $this->conexion;
    }

}
```

Por otro lado, en el fichero `devuelve.php` he eliminado la herencia que había creado. De esta manera, omito el método constructor ya que no lo necesito en el caso de esta clase, que está creada por métodos para obtener, insertar, eliminar o actualizar datos de la BBDD. Actualmente solo he desarrollado un método, `getProducto`, para una consulta sql estática. Éste método recibe por parámetro la variable `$link`, que será obtenida de instanciar la clase `Conexion`. Finalmente, el resultado de la ejecución sql es almacenada en otra variable, `$res_sql`, que será la devuelta por el método.

Adjunto código:

```
require 'conexion.php';

class DevuelveProducto{
    
    public function getProducto($link){
        
        $sql = $link->query('SELECT * FROM personas');
        
        $res_sql = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                
        return $res_sql;        
    }
    
}
```

Por último, el fichero de ejecución:
`poo.php`

```
<?php
require 'devuelve.php';

$link = new Conexion();
$search = new DevuelveProducto();

$search_res = $search->getProducto($link->conexion);
?>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pruebas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <?php
            foreach ($search_res as $elemento){
                
                echo $elemento["nombre"] . "<br>" .
                    $elemento["apellidos"] . "<br>" .
                    $elemento["edad"] . "<br>" .
                    $elemento["tfn"] . "<br>" .
                    "=====================================";
                
            }
        ?>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Agradecer a todos los que han comentado la pregunta!!
Estoy atento a sugerencias y consejos sobre la implementación de este código <3